# Powershell script to pull all ad users and their various group listings to csv

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I need assistance on getting a powershell script that would enable me pull data of all AD users and their various group they belong to .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get the Quest ActiveRoles Server Commandlets [here](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

Then the following script should give you a start.  I am using Excel to store the info, which you can save as a .csv file.  Makes it a little easier with the looping and saving of values.

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.visible = $True 

$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)

$c.Cells.Item(1,1)  = "Users and Groups Report"
$c.Cells.Item(1,2)  = Get-Date
$c.Cells.Item(2,1) = "User"
$c.Cells.Item(2,2) = "Groups"

$d = $c.UsedRange
$d.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$d.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$d.Font.Bold = $True
$d.Font.Size = 14

$introw = 3

$users = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit $howmanyusersdoIwanttoget

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $c.Cells.Item($introw,1) = $user.DisplayName
    $introw +=1

    $groups = Get-QADGroup -ContainsMember $user
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
    $c.Cells.Item($introw,2) = $group.CanonicalName
    $introw +=1
    }
}
```

You should be able to tune this up to meet your exact needs hopefully.